Call an API within a Power BI Dashboard
I have a Power BI dashboard that has some visuals. I also have an API that is hosted on Azure. I want to call the API within the dashboard and do something with it.
The API requires authentication to access it. (I'm using a Microsoft App Registration to provide a token and authenticate by it from the API)
My question is how to authenticate/obtain some access token, whether it's using an identity assigned to the workspace/dashboard or the user's identity?
